# How can I edit the color of this button using a GTK theme?

Tags: themes, gtk

Here is a screenshot of my current theme--Everything works but two things.

Edit: I deleted the picture--Thunderbird had information that was probably not best to show online. Basically, the interface buttons for Nautilus were a different color than that of Thunderbird.

Look at my Nautilus menu: I was able to change its color by editing `button_bg_color` in the gtk.css file. However, Look at the Thunderbird interface's buttons--they are not the same color. Some programs have the color from the Nautilus interface for buttons, while some have Thunderbird's. (These programs are selected randomly to show the differences.) How can I change that?

Also, does anyone know how I can set different applications to use different themes or different parameters? Things like LibreOffice and Evolution (My actual email client) are unreadable with my theme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Gpick `sudo apt-get install gpick` to see which color is it, then locate the color in the gtk.css file, afterwards search the line from gtk.css in the file gtk-widgets.css to make sure which one is it.

I Believe Thunderbird uses the gtkrc file from the gtk 2 portion of the theme so check that. Firefox uses gtk 2 styling not gtk 3 so I guess Thunderbird does too.

Comment: Hey there Uri, we meet again haha! I attempted to use that, but the problem is the button has a gradient, and i can't tell what the original color was supposed to be.

Comment: Got it! The line `fg_color_dark` is what determines it, but as you said, it was in gtk2! Thank you so so much!

Comment: Hey! glad you found it, yeah I was just making a theme, and the gtk 2 bits are just dreadful, what I did in 2 hours for the gtk 3 theme, took me almost 8 hours to make it "work" in gtk 2, god I wish more software gets ported to gtk 3.

Comment: Same here--dumb question, but how long has gtk3 been around?

Comment: Since Last year I believe.